# Is an array an instance of Traversable?

Tags: php

Here is my basic array in my framework

```
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "40"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "41"
}
```

Here is my tests:

```
echo($array instanceof Traversable); // 0
echo(is_array($array)); // 1
```

It seems my standard php array is not an instance of Traversable which seems inconsistent.

Comment: Arrays do not implement `Traversable` in PHP but they will be traversable in `foreach`

Comment: An array is not a class, so it also isn't even capable of extending from any class or interface. Traversable is for things like iterators and such.

Comment: As of PHP 7.1, you can use the pseudo-type `iterable` as a type declaration, which allows use of arrays or something implementing Traversable: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Right, it isn't a Traversable.

The main goal of the interface [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) is to make objects usable with `foreach`.

Answer (score 6):

- Arrays in php are primitive types and primitives cannot inherit from
  classes or implement interfaces
- Therefore the array type in php is not an instance of `Traversable`

What I want to add as additional info is:

- that array and Traversable combined form another type called
  `iterable`
- In other words the  `iterable` type in php is the union of `Traversable | array`
- Interface types like iterator and generator implement Traversable and therefore are of type `iterable`
- This is usually helpful if you implement a function which takes as an argument which we want to iterate over (using foreach) but we don't know beforehand if it will be an array or another `iterable` data structure (like a class which implements `Iterator`).

Answer (score 4):

Whether it is consistent or not, array is just a primitive type in php (not a class) so it won't follow object oriented style of implementing interfaces - in this case Traversable interface.

However, PHP gives us a nice way to convert array into object with **\ArrayObject** which will behave almost like an array (almost because it's actually an object not an array):

```
$someArray = ['foo' => 'bar'];
$objectArray = new \ArrayObject($someArray);

// now you can use $objectArray as you would your $someArray:

// access values
$objectArray['foo']

// add values
$objectArray['boo'] = 'far';

// foreach it
foreach ($objectArray as $key => $value) { ... }

// it also implements \Traversable interface!
$objectArray instanceof \Traversable // true
```